# What makes it possible for a plugin to not able to delete?

Tags: plugins

When I tried to delete a custom-made plugin, the admin wordpress page became a plain white screen with no error messages. What causes this to happen?

Comment: Enable the debug mode and check the error message. `define('WP_DEBUG', true);`

Comment: @ManojKumar I tried that but still isn't showing anything. Still a white screen of death but only to that deletion page, the rest of the admin is still working though.

Comment: What's the URL? `wp-admin/???`

Comment: Does your theme, for example, use code that depends on the custom plugin, or has the backend been hacked to use that code?

Comment: I just found what caused the issue but have no idea why it acted like that. It has this `uninstall.php` inside that plugin's plugin root directory. I commented all it's contents and still the white screen issue persisted. I deleted the file and now I can now successfully **delete** the plugin with out that white screen of death. I still have no clue why that happens

Answer (score 1):

While I don't know exactly what code is responsible, your last comment-- " It has this uninstall.php inside that plugin's plugin root directory"-- gives me a pretty good idea of what is happening.

> If the plugin can not be written without running code within the
>   plugin, then the plugin should create a file named 'uninstall.php' in
>   the base plugin folder. This file will be called, if it exists, during
>   the uninstall process bypassing the uninstall hook.
>
> When using 'uninstall.php' the plugin should always check for the
>   WP_UNINSTALL_PLUGIN constant, before executing. The
>   WP_UNINSTALL_PLUGIN constant is defined by WordPress at runtime during
>   a plugin uninstall, it will not be present if 'uninstall.php' is
>   requested directly. It will also not be present when using the
>   uninstall hook technique. WP_UNINSTALL_PLUGIN is only defined when a
>   uninstall.php file is found in the plugin folder.
>
> https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_uninstall_hook#uninstall.php

That file either has a syntax error and triggers a fatal error, or it does something to prevent deletion. The later behavior seems a bit malicious to me, but I can't say for sure. If you were to post the code from that file a better answer may be possible.